# Stack Overflow Desktop Notifications App

Tags: discussion, notifications

I would like to suggest a desktop app with Skype-style notifications in the corner of the screen.

I would suggest this as an alternative to email notifications because email inboxes get filled with too many things already and something like this would give just the right amount of information needed at a glance.